# Script doesn't work when called from another directory

Tags: fontforge

Not quite sure how to word this properly, but if I run my script within the directory of files it works on, all is fine. If I point the script to the files from another directory, it fails.
I'm sure it's some sort of path expansion or something, but I just can't seem to make it work.

Here is the fontforge script.

```
#!/usr/bin/fontforge
Open($1)
fname = ($1:r)
Print(fname)
SetTTFName(0x409,2,"")
SetFontNames(fname,fname,fname,"")
Print($fullname)
Print($familyname)
Print(GetTTFName(0x409,2))
Generate($1:r + ".ttf")
```

and the command that fails:

```
./fix_font_names ~/Fonts_Other/*
```

and the error:

```
SetFontNames: Invalid character in PostScript name token (probably fontname): : /home/akovia/Fonts_Other/Al Fresco Bold
Called from...
./fix_font_names: line 7
```

The errors change if for example I put $1 in quotes or fname, but the script works perfectly if I call it from within the working directory.

I know I'm missing something obvious, but I just can't figure it out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about fontforge but the syntax looks somewhat similar to shell so I'll have a shot:

Could it be a problem with spaces in variable names? If you run the script from within the directory then the directory name is just `./`, no spaces. However if you run it from elsewhere the directory name is `/home/akovia/Fonts_Other/Al Fresco Bold`, which contains spaces. Try quoting every occurrence of all your variables in the script?

**edit**: just had a quick skim of the language tutorial and it doesn't mention any issues with spaces.

Here's another idea: if you are not in the directory then your `fname` variable contains more than just the font name (it also contains the directory name). Try removing the extra information somehow.

Comment: I bet you are correct. I never thought about fname containing the path as well. Makes perfect sense. Unfortunately I don't know how to modify it. I was also looking for a way to parse the filename via sed so I could extract the proper family name in as well, but I'm lost on how to integrate bash/shell commands into the script. I consider this answered. You have my thanks!

Comment: I noticed in the documentation that you can script it with python as well as this language. If you use python it's trivial: `os.path.basename(fname)`, so that would probably be the easiest solution.

Comment: I found the proper syntax to use from the docs  (:t gives the tail) but I still haven't been able to get much further. That script is called from a bash script that sets some ENV variables, and I think I'm just getting lost having them talk to each other properly. I'm still at it though.